# (NodeJS) Selenium Webdriver findElement.By.css() only returns one value when there are multiple on the page

Tags: css, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selector

Here's the block of code in question:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
var chrome = require('chromedriver')

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build()

driver.get("http://thewebsite.com").then(x => {
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("[title^='ANI:']")).then(selObject => {
     console.log(selObject)
     selObject.getAttribute("title").then(x => console.log(x))
  }) 
})
```

And here's the page source that I'm trying to pull:

```html
<tbody id="CONFGROUP_0">               
    <!-- dynamic content here -->
    <tr id="35534" style="background-color: rgb(228, 225, 229);">
    <td nowrap="" valign="middle" height="30" width="210" title="ANI: 7076  DNIS: 7791" style="font-size: 0.8em;"><div style="overflow: hidden; display: inline; float: left; padding-top: 3px; width: 210px;"><div style="display: inline; padding-top: 4px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 100%;">SOC&nbsp;OPS ALERT</div><input type="text" maxlength="50" style="display: none;"></div><div style="display: none; float: right; padding-right: 10px; height: 30px;"><img src="images/talkshow/03_buttonlower_on.gif" style="margin-top: 6px;"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="35533" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <td nowrap="" valign="middle" height="30" width="210" title="ANI: 8017057799  DNIS: 7076" style="font-size: 0.8em;"><div style="overflow: hidden; display: inline; float: left; padding-top: 3px; width: 210px;"><div style="display: inline; padding-top: 4px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 100%;">8017057799</div><input type="text" maxlength="50" style="display: none;"></div><div style="display: none; float: right; padding-right: 10px; height: 30px;"><img src="images/talkshow/03_buttonlower_on.gif" style="margin-top: 6px;"></div></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

When I run `document.querySelectorAll("[title^='ANI:")` in the Chrome console it returns both of the elements I need. However, when I run the `findElement` found in the code block above it only returns one object.
If I run `driver.executeScript("document.querySelectorAll(\"[title^='ANI:\")")` that will return `null`.

I would expect the `findElement` to return everything it found and from my looking around it looks like it's supposed to do that. I even added a timeout to make sure the page was fully loaded before doing the search and still nothing.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out `findElements` exist and I'm a moron. Thank you all

`elements = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.css("[title^='ANI:']"))`